# How to remove duplicate code using java generics

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have below methods

**BEFORE:**

```
Employee getEmployee(String id){
  String url = "http://localhost" + id;
//duplicate code
}


List<Employee> getEmployees(){
  String url = "http://localhost";
//duplicate code
}
```

In above 2 methods, I have duplicate code, I have tried something like below:

**AFTER:**

```
<T> T get(id){

//here duplicate code from above 2 methods
}


Employee getEmployee(String id){
  return get(id);
}

List<Employee> getEmployees(){
 return get(null);
}
```

I am new to generics, how to resolve above duplicate issue?

Comment: If the code really is an exact duplicate then you shouldn't need generics. Just extract the duplicate code into a private method.

Comment: @orSt how to return dynamic return type?

Comment: @john how would you handle the `null` that you passed? I wonder why is the code even a duplicate? do you fetch a list of `id`s from somewhere and perform `get(id)` for them under the name of `getAllEmployees`?

Comment: Make a private method with the common code. The above is an often occurring pattern, and either one should accept the repetition. But **never use something like `get(null)`**.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glance looks like you have next options:

1. in case you are sure, your “duplicated code” always returns correct type then you can always cast (could cause you runtime issues) 
   *but this has nothing to do with generics, return type can’t depend on null or not*

```
Employee getEmployee(String id){
  return (Employee) get(id);
}

List<Employee> getEmployees(){
 return (List<Employee>) get(null);
}
```

2. another option is to always return List in method *get* and simply get first item in method *getEmployee* (do not forget to check if it is not empty to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException)

I believe there could be better options. Also you can share that removed part, maybe it could be improved. Honestly speaking I have concerns if it’s totally identical.